# Substring boolean does not return expected value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
str1 = "abc"
str2 = "axbg1c"

print(str1 in str2)
```

Why does this code return False instead of True?

Comment: Because `a`, `b` and `c` are in `str2` individually, but `abc` as a substring is not. You need to check whether each character in `str1` is in `str2`. Hint: look at `set` operation.

Comment: What result would you expect for ``"abc" in "xcxbxax"``? What result for ``"abc" in "aabbcc"``?

Answer (score 1):

If you want check all symbols in str2, you can use this:

```
print(all((i for i in str2 if i in str1)))
```

Comment: `all()` can take a "naked" generator expression, which would make this more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The string `"abc"` is not a substring of `"axbg1c"`. All of the characters `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` are in `"axbg1c"`, in the right order even, but the string `"abc"` is nowhere to be found in it. That's what `str1 in str2` is checking for.: The whole `str1` altogether somewhere in `str2`. `"abc" in "xyzabc789"` is `True`, for example.

If you want to know if every character in `str1` is also in `str2`, in any order, do:

`all(c in str2 for c in str1)`

The result will be `True` in your example, because it checks each character in `str1` by itself, and each one is in your `str2`.

If you specifically want to know if they go in the right order as in your example, that would be trickier.